# How do I provide a MWE with a template?

Tags: discussion, mwe

I am running into problems with spacing and figures in my master's thesis. I would like to post it here to see if someone has a solution but I can't seem to get a MWE. The problem is that the template is provided by the school. The spacing issue works fine if I write a new Latex document so I have a feeling it has something to do with the template (ie, the package may be in 'clash' with another package from the template).

How would I go about asking a question here when the MWE is too complicated to provide?

Comment: I think the advice in answers to http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228 applies here as much as anywhere. Minimise your document, removing anything that does not directly impact on the issue. If you've been given a custom class, it may be possible to reduce it to the essentials but for the non-expert that is tricky, and so providing a link is often the best way.

Comment: If you are keen on also learning TeX in the meantime, you can start removing parts of your template until you still have the problem but all the unnecessary parts are taken out such as author formatting the title page aligment etc. Then you can either solve it yourself or bring it over to here and we can have a look. That is actually how I got into LaTeX programming too.